# Spring Boot Serialize JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have 3 same models, with different field name. I try to make code less.

```
public class Car {

private CarResults carResults;
}

public class Bike{

private BikeResults bikeResults;
}

public class Plane{

private PlaneResults planeResults;
}
```

PlaneResults, BikeResults, CarResults

is class which has inside only field Results results;

I have following JSON and all working fine

```
{
  "bikeResults":{
    "results": {
      etc
    }
  }
}

{
  "carResults":{
    "results": {
      etc
    }
  }
}

{
  "planeResults":{
    "results": {
      etc
    }
  }
}
```

All is the same, but the main wrapper is different, so i need to have 3 same models.
How to avoid them, and make code more clear.

I tried `@JsonAnyGetter` it works, but i have json

```
{
  "bikeResults":{
      etc
  }
}
```

So, i lost "results" path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved an issue with

```
@JsonTypeName("results")
@JsonTypeInfo(include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
```

on my Results class

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `jackson` library, you can try to use `@JsonProperty` and `@JsonAlias` for that.

```
public class VehicleResult {
    private Result results;
}

public class Vehicle {
    @JsonProperty("bikeResults")
    @JsonAlias("carResults")
    @JsonAlias("planeResults")
    private VehicleResult result;
}
```

Read this [Mapping Multiple JSON Fields to a Single Java Field](https://www.baeldung.com/json-multiple-fields-single-java-field)

Comment: Actually it is not what i am searching. On deserialization it works, but the main for me is the choose how to map field name on serialization. For me is better JsonAnyGetter, but the main is that how to get rid of defining nested wrapper class. I do not want to make bikeResults,getResults().getResults(). Then structure will be fine. I need wrap my json class with outer json as in example